# Is there any significance to the exact number of gold pieces?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, the-curse-of-the-black-pearl

> "This is Aztec gold. One of 882 identical pieces they delivered in a stone chest to Cortés himself."

Is there any significance to that number, 882? Either in universe, or out of it.

Comment: What makes you think that there may be a significance and that it's not just a random number?

Comment: @Mithrandir that's why I'm asking if there _is_ any significance, instead of assuming there is a asking _what_ it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there 882 pieces of Aztec gold in the first Pirates of the Carribean movie?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070702162710AAjFsab) (just kidding, it's Yahoo! Answers, but you're not the first to ask)

Comment: [Out of universe.](http://www.numberempire.com/882).

Comment: Out of universe: 882 is the smallest number (after 0 and 1) whose digital sums in bases 2, 3, 5, and 7 are all equal. [oeis.org/A135127](http://oeis.org/A135127)